# Spring Boot JPA Operation

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

Spring Boot Maven Project
Oracle 19c

I have 100 repositories corresponding to 100 tables.
Currently, there is a requirement that when each repository undergoes an update or delete, I need to write its pre-modification data into a history table and store it as JSON->CLOB for subsequent undo records.
I would like to inquire if JPA has native syntax or annotations to achieve this purpose?

Comment: If you are looking for JPA specific syntax then the [Oracle] tag is irrelevant. If you are looking for a non-JPA solution then write a database trigger for each of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Hibernate, have a look at [Hibernate interceptors](https://mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-interceptor-example-audit-log/).

However, if the goal is to keep old versions of records to revert to, you might want to take a look at versioning libraries like Envers or Javers, rather than reinvent the wheel.